# Why does SQL Server give me a column twice the size I requested?

Tags: sql-server, azure

After executing a `CREATE TABLE` for a temporary table I was verifying that the size of the field fits what I need to use.

To my surprise, SQL Server (Azure SQL) is reporting that the table now has double the size. Why is this?

This is what I executed, in order:

```
CREATE TABLE #A ( Name NVARCHAR(500) not null ) 
EXEC tempdb..sp_help '#A'
```

[image: double the size]

Comment: A `NVARCHAR` column **always** stores every character with **2 bytes** - so asking for 500 2-byte characters obviously results in 1000 bytes .....

Comment: @marc_s Why not make that an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: If you need to find the actual width of a column you can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS View: SELECT
 CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM
 Tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
 TABLE_NAME LIKE '#A%'
 AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Name'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NVARCHAR shows 2 bytes per character. So if the size is 500 it shows size as 1000. It is to store unicode format data.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind to comment on why sp_help shows the storage size instead of the logical size?

Answer (score 6):

An `NVARCHAR` column in SQL Server **always** stores every character with 2 bytes.

So if you're asking for 500 characters (at 2 bytes each), obviously this results in column size of 1000 bytes.

That's been like this in SQL Server forever - this isn't new or Azure specific.